How to create computed/calculated field in Prisma?
It is possible to create the gamesPlayed field "on the fly" by the database?
What should be the code in the schema.prisma file? it's from ts to mysql
model Teams {
  id            String @id @default(uuid())
  leagueId      String?
  name          String
  place         String
  totalWon      Int     @default(0)
  totalDrawn    Int     @default(0)
  totalLost     Int     @default(0)
  gamesPlayed   Int     // this field should be generated by the database as totalWon+totalDrawn+totalLost
  totalPoints   Int     @default(0)
  goalsFor      Int     @default(0)
  goalsAgainst  Int     @default(0)
}

Thank you

This open request shows there is no way to do it with Prisma: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6336

IMO, Prisma seems to have been developed by folks who don't actually know anything about SQL databases. For example, they still don't support join queries for MySQL.

Thanks to @bill karvin comment
There is no support
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6336
